# Why is GNU parallel as slow as single-CPU xargs for this command?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have a bash command that takes a directory full of XML files, runs them through XSLT to CSV's, and combines all of the transforms into a single file. I've been attempting to use `parallel`, but the CPU usage never goes above 100% for this command. I cannot use `xargs` for this because the output gets interspersed.

This takes ~30 seconds, but again, the output is interspersed:

`find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -P8 xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt`

This takes ~90 seconds. Single Core.

`find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt`

This also takes ~90 seconds. As slow as single-core, and CPU useage from `top` never goes above 100%.

`find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 | parallel -0 xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt`

This seems so dead simple, I don't know what I'm missing. Could anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: What is the size of xml files? Maybe bottleneck is disk operations?

Comment: There are 17698 XML files with a median file size of 53947 bytes. Not sure how that could be true though, because xargs parallel finishes in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel has an overhead per job in the order of 5 ms. So if your jobs are short lived, then this overhead will be the limiting factor.

`xsltproc` can take several files as arguments so this may help:

```
find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 |
  parallel -X -0 xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt
```

*Edit*

If this does the right thing:

```
find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 |
  xargs -0 -P8 xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt
```

(except for the mixed output), then the `-X` solution must also do the right thing. The `xargs -P8` solution will put many filenames after `transform.xsl`. The same is the case for `-X`. Are you sure the output from `xargs -P8` is the full (though mixed) output?

If `xlstproc` only works reliable with a single file name, try this:

```
find /path/to/xml -type f -iname '*.xml' |
  parallel --pipe -N100 --round-robin parallel xsltproc transform.xsl > out.txt
```

This spawns a `parallel` per cpu core. So you should now either see 100% CPU usage of all CPUs or 100% disk I/O. If the files are cached then you should see 100% CPU usage - a lot of it from GNU Parallel, though.

Comment: The first one runs in 4 seconds, amazing!

I was not able to get the second one to run, some of the file names contain spaces so maybe that was an issue.

```
unable to parse -
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Re-adding print0 to the second command resulted in blocksize error messages.

```
parallel: Warning: A record was longer than 1048576. Increasing to --blocksize 1363150.
```

Comment: So it turns out using -X doesn't work either. It splits the filenames into groups, but only runs XSLT proc on one of the groups. That's why it ran so quickly. Still haven't found a solution then yet that uses parallel.